# Circular selection tool is stuck on the cursor after pressing alt+c

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, shortcut, selection-tools

I am modeling a car. While modelling I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> instead of <kbd>C</kbd> for circular select tool. The circular select tool came anyway but now I'm unable to exit the tool. It has got stuck to the cursor. When I press <kbd>C</kbd> again the new circular tool comes over the stuck one.

I'm not able to do anything. I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> again to undo it but its all in vain. So to rectify it I opened a new blender file and pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and same problem appears. The cursor got stuck on circular tool.

[image]

**Q:** What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi. Blender comes with a screenshot function: *Main menu > Window > Save Screenshot*...

Comment: thanks for advice.i tried using windows screenshot feature but in that case the cursor error is left out in ss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to exit it by pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> or by changing the selection tool in the top right.[image]

Comment: thanks. Problem solved :)

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, consider to accept the answer. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour @S.T